# Auto-detect headphone jack

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa

I am using ALSA on Arch Linux on a MacBook Air 5,2 (mid 2012). This is my first time using alsa by itself (without any tools that come with gnome), so I may have not configured something in order to make the jack work. I would like to be able to have it auto-detect when I plug headphones into the jack. Can anyone help me do this? The relevant kernel module for this setup is `snd_hda_intel` but I'm not sure if I have to configure the kernel module or ALSA in order to get this to work.

Comment: You have unmuted the Headphone channel in `alsamixer`?

Comment: Haha that was it thanks. I will edit my question to find out how to auto-detect when headphones are plugged in